# Merge two lists (string and int) together

Tags: c#

My problem is that I have 2 lists, that I get dynamically but they will be of same size every time, and I need merge them in one list, for example I have

```
List<string> chars = [aaa],[bbb],[ccc];
List<int> numbers= [1][2][3];
```

I want to get 3th list that will have combined data like `List<?> combo= [[aaa][1]],[[bbb][2]],[[ccc][3]]`
Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you show compiling code? What type has the desired result at all?

Comment: this seems to be a job for [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Please indicate what should occur if they are NOT the same size here.

Comment: they will be same size...

Comment: "they wont be of same size every time" and "they will be same size" ... well.....

Comment: Now you confuse me with your question portion of  " so they wont be of same size every time,"

Comment: @Carsten Maybe some kind of quantum programming technique?

Comment: @UweKeim I guess it's Schrödingers Lists ... but why should the specifications on SO be better than in RL?

Comment: sry mistake in question.

Comment: You guys are complicating things too much - I'd say it's a reasonable assumption  that the Length of the two arrays will be equal, but not known at compile-time. Hence - "not same size every time", but "same size".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) and a tuple:

```
List<Tuple<string, int>> combo = chars.Zip(numbers, (s, i) => Tuple.Create(s, i)).ToList();
```

Comment: This works fine, thx for help everyone :)

Answer (score 3):

```
chars.Select((x, i) => new object[] { x, numbers[i] }).ToArray();
```